# Unable to fork in spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to bring up a spring boot application in pre-integration-phase and run some integration tests against it.

Below is the configuration, in fork mode false, i can verify that the application is coming up but even after turning fork true either by command line or via configuration the application is not coming up in fork jvm but in the same jvm.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.settlement.Settlement</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -DconfigDbPropertiesFile=../../common/profile/src/main/resources/${user.name}.properties -Dsettlement.rest.port=9090 -DcomponentPort=1779
                    </jvmArguments>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-service</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-service</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

command to execute

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=Settlement,Settlement,Settlement,BASE_PERSISTENCE_CONSTANTS -Dspring-boot.run.fork=true
```

Comment: Please read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Answer (score 1):

This maven code works for me

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.ashomokdev.springdockerec2.SpringDockerEc2Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```